# Duda sobre la etiqueta <body>, <html> y :root en css

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda respecto a esto, he visto a muchos como en css modifican mucho lo que es el "cuerpo" (body), pero yo por ejemplo hice un proyecto basándome de la idea de un video donde el usa el body en el css pero yo no lo hice, yo a base de esto esperaba darme una idea de que diferencias iban a ver entre editar el body y no en mi archivo css.

Mi duda es, qué cambios o estilos podría aplicar al body **(exceptuando el fondo de pantalla como color e imágenes y todo lo que conlleve ajustar ese fondo)** en mi archivo css que sean fundamentales para esta etiqueta?

Lo mismo pregunto para **:root** y la etiqueta **html**, veo como muchos aplican a esa etiqueta html y tenia la duda de si es lo mismo que usar el *{}

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: body, html o :root hace referencia a un único objeto del DOM, mientras que `*` hace referencia a ABSOLUTAMENTE TODOS LOS OBJETOS QUE AÑADAS A TU DOM!! El asterisco es un comodín, e indica precisamente *CUALQUIER ELEMENTO*. Los atributos que indicas (padding, margin y box-sizing) normalmente se setean en el html/body/root para tener una "base limpia" sobre la que trabajar. No quieres que todos tus componentes tengan 0 padding y 0 margin siempre, no hay necesidad de setearlo así para todo puesto que acabarás sobrescribiéndolo constantemente para otros elementos!

Comment: Hay algo que destacar del body, html y :root que siempre deberia agregar en mi codigo o depende lo que necesite?